# dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sbt due to Package java2-runtime is not installed on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, sbt

I want to install sbt on an Ubuntu machine where I manually installed Java. I use the following code for installing Java manually on the machine:

```
sudo curl -L -s http://wake.s3.amazonaws.com/blobs/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.gz -o /usr/local/jdk-oracle.gz
cd /usr/local
sudo tar xzf /usr/local/jdk-oracle.gz
sudo rm -rf usr/local/jdk-oracle.gz
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_51
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_51" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
echo "PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java" 1
```

When downloading and installing sbt afterwards with

```
curl -o /tmp/sbt.deb http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-native-packages/org/scala-sbt/sbt//0.13.0/sbt.deb
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/sbt.deb
```

it throws the following error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sbt:
 sbt depends on java2-runtime; however:
  Package java2-runtime is not installed.

dpkg: error processing sbt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sbt
```

Installing java through the webupd8 PPA is not an option. I have also had a look at this manual that distinguishes between installing JRE and JDK (http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux), but it still can't find java2-runtime. How can I install sbt with a manual Java installation on Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you already tried [this](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html#unix)?

Comment: It works. It makes the most sense of course. I didn't think about using the manual installation of sbt. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

(Re-posting this from comment above as an answer, since it could solve the problem)

There's also the option to manually install SBT (see [here for Unix](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html#unix)), which shouldn't be too difficult.